# use subfolders in homegroup

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to build a metro-app which shall load an image file from another computer in the same homegroup (all computers use windows 8 x64 with working homegroup). All samples I found do not use subfolders or use the filepicker.
Since all my images are in the same folder and I know their names I do not want to use the filepicker.
I activated "Pictures Library" in the appxmanifest and I can list the directories/computers in the homegroup but I'm stuck in opening files or subfolders.

Here's what I did:

```
var folder = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.HomeGroup.GetFolderAsync("homegroupname");

foreach (var a in await folder.GetFoldersAsync())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(a.Name.ToString());
}
```

This gave me a list of the computers of the homegroup (as expected).

Here's what I tried without success:

```
folder = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.HomeGroup.GetFolderAsync(@"homegroupname\computername");
folder = await folder.GetFolderAsync(@"computername");
```

These attempts didn't work and I ran out of ideas. Do I have to allow the folder somewhere? Is my way of opening the (sub-)folders the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with the following (nearly intuitive) approach:
I create a CommonFileQuery for files of the right type and choose the one with fitting name.

```
List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
fileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate, fileTypeFilter);

var query = KnownFolders.HomeGroup.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await query.GetFilesAsync();
StorageFile file = fileList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "123_123.jpg");
```